# Configure trickle to add guestOS

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, bandwidth, throttling

I want to configure Trickle to prioritize my bandwidth with an installed app on ubuntu,

I understand the basic config:

```
[ssh]
Priority = 1
Time-Smoothing = 0.1
Length-Smoothing = 1
[www]
Priority = 2
Time-Smoothing = 5
Length-Smoothing = 10
[ftp]
Priority = 8
```

but how can I use virtualbox? Or the possible the command for the guests running in virtualbox?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can broaden the effects of trickle to the entire guest operating system (as a child process of the host that is), if that is what you were hoping to do. That being said, any ssh/www/ftp traffic from your guest could be throttled by trickle as long as your guest is configured with NAT networking I would imagine.